# Putting Multiple Pdfs in a MemoryStream

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, telerik

I'm trying to take preexisting pdf files and read them all into a memory stream to then be shown on a telerik pdf viewer. If I just do one file it works but as soon as I try multiple files it gives me a internal null error (object ref not set to blah blah) and can't step in the code to see where its actualy null. Am I doing this wrong or something?

```
        List<string> applicableReports = CurrentWizard.GetApplicableReports();
        previousReportsStream = new MemoryStream();

        Stream[] streams = new Stream[applicableReports.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < streams.Length; i++)
        {
            streams[i] = new MemoryStream(DocumentHelper.Instance.ConvertFileToByteArray(applicableReports[i]));
            streams[i].CopyTo(previousReportsStream);
        }

        RadPdfViewer radPdfViewer = new RadPdfViewer();
        RadFixedDocument document = new PdfFormatProvider(previousReportsStream, FormatProviderSettings.ReadAllAtOnce).Import();
        radPdfViewer.Document = document;
```

This is where error is thrown:

```
    RadFixedDocument document = new PdfFormatProvider(previousReportsStream, FormatProviderSettings.ReadAllAtOnce).Import();
```

DocumentHelper File to byte[]:

```
    public byte[] ConvertFileToByteArray(string fileName)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
        byte[] fileData = null; 

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
            fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)fileStream.Length);
        }

        return fileData;
    }
```

Comment: which line throw the exception? and what is blah blah?

Comment: Sorry updated the question. Blah is me being lazy and not finishing "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" The stream ins't null though which is weird

Comment: If the exception is indeed thrown when your code executes the line `new PdfFormatProvider(...).Import()`, it looks like the exception is thrown by PdfFormatProvider. Check the stacktrace of the exception, which tells you which code line (or method) threw the exception. Most likely PdfFormatProvider stumbles over your stream unable to handle any further data behind the data of the 1st PDF. (Note, you cannot just slap together the data of several PDF files in one stream and hope that PdfFormatProvider will somehow make sense of it...)

Comment: Also, which PDFViewer version are you using? In a version from 2013, PdfFormatProvider.Import() had a bug which caused a NullReferenceException ([see here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/pdfformatprovider-import-throws-null-reference-exception))

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is the h process is out of memory because the code  creates many MemoryStream object and does not dispose them.

Try change code to this:

```
        List<string> applicableReports = CurrentWizard.GetApplicableReports();
        previousReportsStream = new MemoryStream();


        try
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < streams.Length; i++)
            {
                using( MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(DocumentHelper.Instance.ConvertFileToByteArray(applicableReports[i]))
                {
                memStream.CopyTo(previousReportsStream);
                }
            }

            RadPdfViewer radPdfViewer = new RadPdfViewer();
            RadFixedDocument document = new PdfFormatProvider(previousReportsStream, FormatProviderSettings.ReadAllAtOnce).Import();
            radPdfViewer.Document = document;
       }
       finally
       {
          previousReportsStream.Close();
       }
```

As MemoryStream implements the IDisposable interface, you call dispose it to free the native resources; if not, the it will lead to high memory usage.

Please read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Yeah this still didn't work...I'm starting to think it's something like elgonzo said here: http://www.telerik.com/forums/pdfformatprovider-import-throws-null-reference-exception